# how to get column names from an array and export to excel

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 5
    [member_type] => 3
    [member_name] => Abin
    [email] => abin@newagesmb.com
    [username] => abin
    [about_user] => 
    [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
    [description] => 
    [membership_type] => 0
    [joindate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [membership_expirydate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [image] => 
    [active] => N
    [approved] => Y
    [varified] => N
    [coach] => N
    [paid_user] => N
    [fb_unique_id] => 
    [fb_access_tocken] => 
    [gender] => M
    [latitude] => 
    [longitude] => 
    [firstname] => 
    [lastname] => 
    [location] => 
    [avg_speed] => 6-8 Miles/Hour
    [twitter_tocken] => 
    [twitter_tocken_secret] => 
    [sponsor] => N
    [no_of_runs] => 0
    [rand] => 
    [distance] => 
    [country_id] => 
    [state_id] => 
)
```

This is my array . I need to export these values to excel. The array can be multi dimensional.

Comment: And what is your problem and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, If you mean that your array keys are your column names than you can use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys),

```
$columns = array_keys($your_array);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 14
    [15] => 15
) This is the result i got. i need column names

Comment: I guess you have two dimensional array, try with `array_keys($your_array[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Better use `foreach` loop

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
   $contents[]=$key;
}
```

Once you get the keys you can export like shown below

```
<?php
$filename ="excelreport.xls";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
print_r($contents);
 ?>
```

Comment: echo $contents;Gives the result Array() on excel sheet

Comment: I hope u atleast got the column names?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 14
    [15] => 15
) this is the value in the excel sheet now

Comment: You are definitely doing some thing wrong i guess...tht shud definitely print the key values

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(your data);

foreach($array as $col=>$value){

       $ff []= $col;
}


$data = $ff[1].",".$ff[2].",".$ff[3].","....so on

$excel = "xfile.csv";

file_put_content($excel, $data PHP_EOL, PHP_APPEND)
```

Comment: You can do it using CSV

Comment: hi i need excel itself :(

Comment: @user3463573 - If you need Excel itself, then which of the many available libraries have you looked at using, and what problems do you have with them?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library:

```
// Require the library
require_once '../libraries/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel spreadsheet object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Add your array of data to the PHPExcel spreadsheet object
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->fromArray(array_keys($myArrayOfData[0]), null, 'A1')
    ->fromArray($myArrayOfData, null, 'A2');

// Save the PHPExcel spreadsheet object to an OfficeOpenXML format Excel file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('mySparklyShineyExcelFile.xlsx');
```